# SQL Statement in ClearQuest causes ORA-00907:missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, clearquest

I am trying to extract data from ClearQuest which is running an oracle database behind a nice Eclipse-based front-end. Using the built-in query-builder I cannot limit the data to be supplied enough to get me where I want.

My aim: I wish to extract data from two tables. Table 2 has a many-to-one relationship to Table 1. When pulling data from the database I wish to extract the latest record from Table 2 that has a relationship to a specified set of records in Table 1.

My attempt: I started writing a simple query that used a second select to get the latest record from Table 2. I am unable to setup an oracle server on my machine and have therefore had to try the query in mysql and tweak it for oracle. This is the query:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.set_date
from test_table t1, link_table t2
where t2.test_id = t1.id
      and t2.set_date = (select set_date
                         from link_table
                         where t1.id = test_id
                         order by set_date desc
                         limit 1)
      and t1.state = 'Closed';
```

Running this in MySQL works fine! 
Changing the query to match Oracle standards gives me this;

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.name,t2.set_date 
FROM   test_table t1,link_table t2 
WHERE  t2.test_id = t1.id 
       AND t2.set_date = (SELECT set_date 
                          FROM   link_table 
                          WHERE  t1.id = test_id 
                                 AND ROWNUM = 1 
                          ORDER  BY set_date DESC) 
       AND t1.state = 'Closed';
```

Which when testing to run it through an Oracle Formatter (such as [Instant SQL Formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm)) it runs through fine. But, when entering the query into ClearQuest to extract data it gives me the error; `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`.

I have tried changing this all morning and can't get it to work. What am I missing?

Comment: According to [this support response](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21121098), nested SQL statements are not supported. Could this be an explanation?

Comment: That could certainly be an explanation. The problem is that I can't really get around using nested selects (at least not to my knowledge...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try the below code:- Performance increases using analytical query compared to nested query.

```
   select t1.id,t1.name,t2.set_date 
FROM   test_table t1,(select * from (select set_date,test_id,row_number() over (partition by test_id order by set_date desc ) rn from link_table) where rn =1) t2 
WHERE  t2.test_id = t1.id AND t1.state = 'Closed';
```

I couldn't test the same . Please revert in case you encounter issues

Comment: I will give this a test as soon as the query is done.

Comment: Well! As it happens the program crashes after a few minutes of being on 5%... I think this has to do with my tables being a bit big. I will have to export most of the data and perform the selection in another program. This did solve the issue with the error though! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think row number can be calculated until the order by is processed.  Thus it's not available at that level within the sub select.  If however you alias the sub select and add where rownum = 1 to the outer where clause it should work.

Comment: I think that it should work fine, removing the ORDER BY in the sub-query like you suggested has removed the generated error. Now it just needs to sit for a while to run the query (currently at 5% and not moving...)

Comment: https://forums.oracle.com/message/2696199  here's why I think it will work :D.  However it may be faster/more efficient to create the sub query once inline in the from statement thus it only has to order once. instead of for every row in the t1, t2.  And I would try  over partition listed below.  use of analytics in queries has AMAZING performance.